# Is following a normal field extension?

Tags: abstract-algebra, extension-field

> Is $\mathbb{Q}(i)\in\mathbb{Q}(i)(\sqrt[4]{5})$ a normal field extension and if not give an extension of it which is normal over $\mathbb{Q}(i)$.

I saw $((i)(\sqrt[4]{5}))^2=-\sqrt[]{5}$ and I guess this is the minimal polynomial which has $(i\sqrt[4]{5})$ as root, but it is not a polynomial in $\mathbb{Q}(i)$ so I would say it is not normal and a new extension which might be normal might be $\mathbb{Q}(i+1)(\sqrt[4]{5})$. I know that this extension is normal over $\mathbb{Q}(i)(\sqrt[4]{5})$ but I am not sure if it follows also for $\mathbb{Q}(i)$.

Would be very happy for help.

Comment: It's a splitting field (think fourth roots), so it is normal.

Comment: The notation $\Bbb Q(i)\in\Bbb Q(i)(\sqrt[4]{5})$ is wrong. And your proposed extension $\Bbb Q(i+1)(\sqrt[4]{5})$ is in fact *the same field* as the given one $\Bbb Q(i)(\sqrt[4]{5})$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin that's true but why do I need to take the polynomial of fourth degree and not for example the one of second?

Comment: The extension does not have degree $2$ over $\mathbb{Q}(i)$, so it would be hard to do it with a polynomial of degree $2$.

Comment: "I guess this is the minimal polynomial"... you never wrote a polynomial, and yet you keep asking whether you can take "that polynomial"....

Comment: @ArturoMagidin true, I meant $x^2+\sqrt[]{5}$.

Comment: That's not a polynomial in $\mathbb{Q}(i)[x]$, so how could you claim that your field is the splitting field of that polynomial *over $\mathbb{Q}(i)$*?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin exactly, since it isn't a Polynomial with coefficients in $\mathbb{Q}(i)$ then I was concluding that it is not a normal field.

Comment: @Annalisa: That argument is specious. The requirement is that there be a polynomial with coefficients in $\mathbb{Q}(i)$ such that the extension is its splitting field. You say "Well, here's a polynomial with coefficients in the wrong field which has this element as a root, therefore there is no polynomial with coefficients in $\mathbb{Q}(i)$ such that this is a splitting field"? Using that argument, $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ is not a normal extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ because it's a root of $x-\sqrt{2}$, and this is not in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin that's true. it was a mistake. Would you then know a case in which it would not be normal over Q(i)? So that I get a better understanding of it.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I mean which possible roots of a polynomial in $\mathbb{Q}(i)$ would not be contained in an extension which has roots and i in it?

Comment: $\mathbb{Q}(i)(\sqrt[8]{5})$, which contains some, but not all, of the roots of $x^8-5$.

Answer (score 2):

It is a normal extension. Note that the roots of the polynomial $x^4-5$ over $\mathbb Q(i)$ are exactly given by $\sqrt[4]5$, $i\sqrt[4]5$, $-\sqrt[4]5$ and $-i\sqrt[4]5$. These are all contained in $\mathbb Q(i,\sqrt[4]5)$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That is true, but how do I know that I have to take this as minimal polynomial and not the one that I have taken for example?

Comment: @Annalisa: You never wrote down a polynomial, let alone one with coefficients in $\mathbb{Q}(i)$.

Comment: @Annalisa For your example $x^2+\sqrt5$ is not a polynomial over $\mathbb Q(i)$.

Comment: @CHENRK exactly, therefore I was concluding that the extension is not normal. But apparently this is not correct. I am only not yet sure why. Must I find the polynomial in $\mathbb Q(i)$ and then conclude something about it being normal or not?

Comment: @Annalisa Yes, since for a field $F$, a finite separable extension $F(\alpha)/F$ is determined by an irreducible polynomial $f$ over $F$ which has $\alpha$ as a root. Then you should consider whether that is the splitting field of $f$.